# Javascript - Record audio from mp3 file

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, mediastream

I want to use `MediaRecorder` in order to record an existing mp3 file. I tried to pass an `Audio` element as a source to `MediaRecorder`, after calling captureStream() but it doesn't works.

```
new MediaRecorder(new Audio('./audio.mp3').captureStream(), {
    audioBitsPerSecond: 16000
});
```

The error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'MediaRecorder':
>   The MediaRecorder cannot start becausethere are no audio or video
>   tracks available.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `play()` that audio... (and wait it actually does), otherwise there is nothing in your stream to get recorded.

```
const aud = new Audio('./audio.mp3');
aud.play().then( () => {
  const stream = aud.captureStream();
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = ...

});
```